# How can I get version Information for multiple computers? -Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell-3.0

I am trying to write a script to determine whether or not a server is running `MSSQLSERVER` or `MSSQL$*` (some instance of SQL Server) by going through a text file of server names separated by a new line. The code works for the first server and outputs the correct version and engine edition, but for all of the other servers it will only tell me whether or not they running SQL Server, and not output the version and engine edition. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

```
Clear-Host

$Name1 = "MSSQLSERVER"
$Name2 = "MSSQL$*"

$computers = Get-Content "E:\computers.txt"

$saveAs = 'E:\SQL_Report.txt'

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    try{
        $Service1 = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer {Get-Service MSSQLSERVER}
        $Service2 = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer {Get-Service MSSQL$*}

        if($Service1 -Match $Name1 -Or $Service2 -Match $Name2){

            "$computer Running MSSQL"
            [reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") | out-null
            $srv = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" "$computer"
            $srv.Version
            $srv.EngineEdition 
        }
        else{
            "$computer Not running MSSQL"
        }
    }
    catch{
        "$computer, Not Accessable, $_"
        continue
    }
}
```

Here is an example of current output:

Database_name1 Running SQL Server

Major  Minor  Build  Revision

---

10     50     6220   -1
EnterpriseOrDeveloper
Database_name2 Not running SQL Server
Cannot find any service with service name 'MSSQLSERVER'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSSQLSERVER:String) [Get-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand

Database_name3 Running SQL Server
Cannot find any service with service name 'MSSQLSERVER'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSSQLSERVER:String) [Get-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand